# Registrar un usuario a partir de un formulario en Django

Tags: django, django-models

Buenas, tengo un modelo que hereda de AbstractUser:

***Models.py***

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser,models.Model):
    dni=models.CharField(
        verbose_name="DNI",
        max_length=9,
        blank=False,
    )
    clave = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Contraseña",
        max_length=20,
        blank=False
    )
    validado= models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Usuario"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Usuarios"
        ordering = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {} - {} -{}".format(self.username,self.first_name,self.last_name,self.email,self.dni)
```

Cuando se registre este usuario pasará a formar parte de la base de datos de usuarios de django.

***Views.py***

```
class UsuarioCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
template_name = "common/usuarios/Usuarioform.html"
model = Usuario
fields = ['first_name','last_name','email','clave','dni']
login_url = "auth-login"
group_required = ['Administrador','Básico']
success_url = reverse_lazy("usuarios:usuario-list")
success_message = "Usuario registrado satisfactoriamente"
```

El problema es que cuando registro el usuario, la contraseña no se guarda en la base de datos de User por tema de cifrado, alguien sabe como se soluciona?

Gracias.

Comment: Cuando dices que no se guarda por tema de cifrado a que te refieres exactamente, por otro lado, hablas de tu campo `clave` o del campo `password` que trae el modelo de usuario de Django por defecto?

Comment: Del campo 'password', el usuario se registra bien en la base de datos de usuario, pero cuando quiero comprobar la clave me dice esto:



Contraseña:
No se ha establecido la clave.

Las contraseñas no se almacenan en texto plano, por lo que no hay forma de ver la de este usuario, pero puede cambiar la contraseña usando este formulario.

Comment: ¿Cómo creas el usuario? y ¿En que parte te sale ese error?

Comment: El usuario lo creo usando la vista [UsuarioCreateView] y un template, me recoge todos los datos perfectamente. Pero a la hora de consultar en el apartado de admin de Django me sale ese mensaje en el usuario, es decir, que por algún motivo la clave no se recoge correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según veo en tus modelos, definiste un campo llamado `clave`, el cual, para ti es la `contraseña`, y este es el problema, que mientras que para ti esa es la clave, para django no. Django en su modelo de usuario, provee un campo reservado llamado `password`, este campo, es el cual por medio de un algoritmo de cifrado y la llave privada que tienes en tus settings, cifra la contraseña al momento de guardarla en la base de datos, como tu en tu vista de `UsuarioCreateView` estas pasando un campo llamado `clave`, y no uno llamado `password`, entonces django no está haciendo el cifrado de ninguna clave, por lo cual, el usuario se guarda sin contraseña, mi recomendación es eliminar el campo `clave`, y usar `password`, así todo debería trabajar adecuadamente. [Aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/) está el proceso de como debes usar el `AbstractUser`.

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda comenta

Answer (score 1):

Hermano es por que es de AbstracUser, mira yo lo registro de esta manera, y es desde Form !!

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CreateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, error_messages=ERROR_MESSAGE_USER)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.PasswordInput(),error_messages=ERROR_MESSAGE_PASSWORD)
    email = forms.CharField(error_messages=ERROR_MESSAGE_EMAIL)

class Meta:
    model= User
    fields =('username','password','email')
```

ya en .views

```
from .forms import CreateUserForm
class Create(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('client:login')
    template_name = 'clients/create.html'
    model = User
    form_class = CreateUserForm

def form_valid(self,form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.set_password(self.object.password)
    self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```